# Core vector machine implementation

Tags: svm, algorithms, kernel-trick, large-data

I came across the following article :
http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume6/tsang05a/tsang05a.pdf, Core Vector Machines:
Fast SVM Training on Very Large Data Sets.

The approach looks very promising, however I have been unable to find any implementation of this method.

Could anyone recommand me one ? If no such library exists, is there any good reason so few people got interested in it ?

Comment: The following paper http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume8/loosli07a/loosli07a.pdf stresses the pitfalls of the method, but also confirms the efficiency over large datasets...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize this question has been open for a while, but I've implemented the method from that paper in Python a few years ago. It is not a ready to use library, but I suppose it could be useful for experimentation. It has been uploaded to [GitHub](https://github.com/jschuhmacher/cvm/blob/master/src/train/cvm.py).